# How to give permission in web.config file for users,admin,others?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web-config

I am getting confused to give permission for user's ,admin and others in web.config.
this is my web.config

```
 <authorization>      
  <deny users="*"/>
  <allow users ="neerajjadon"  roles ="Admin">     
</authorization>
```

Now i login with name neerajjadon then one new page is coming on this page i have one link button to move to another page.If i am clicking on this linkbutton then its not going to next page it is going to login page again.
Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the other page is in a sub folder then perhaps you could add in a seperate web.config in that directory with:

```
 <authorization>  
   <deny users="*"/> 
   <allow users ="neerajjadon"  roles ="Admin">   
 </authorization>
```

or another option, probably not practical but you can add authorization to specific pages like:

```
   <location path="page 1.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
       <allow users ="neerajjadon"  roles ="Admin"> 
       <deny users="*"/>
      </authorization>
     </system.web>
   </location>
```